# How to express height?

Tags: grammar

If something is very above. Then can one say that it is at height instead of saying that it is at long height?
Another example, if a city is 7000 m above sea level than to express its aboveness can one say that this city is at height or say that this city is at long height.

Comment: *This city sits at a great height above sea level. This city has a high elevation.*

Answer (score 3):

We don't say *at height* or *at long height; long* is used only of distances on the ground.

We can say 'The city is at a height of 7,000 m above sea level,' or 'it is at a great height.'

Comment: I think he doesn't know to talk about its *altitude*.

Comment: Can we say much height?

Comment: Yes, as in "the plane didn't lose much height", but not in the examples given earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would need to say “it’s high above sea level”. If you just say it’s “very high” then people could think it’s like a castle or sits on a hill so is high compared with surrounding land.